# Why in for loop value assigned to a temp variable not print as it is?

Tags: java, oop

**My Demo Program :**

```
public static void main(String x[])
{
    int tempVal = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; tempVal = i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Value Of i: "+i +" _tempVal:"+tempVal);
    }
}
```

**Output :**

Value Of i: 0 _tempVal:5

Value Of i: 1 _tempVal:0

Value Of i: 2 _tempVal:1

Value Of i: 3 _tempVal:2

Value Of i: 4 _tempVal:3

**Why variable "tempVal" is not having same value as 'i' ?**

Comment: Because you're post-incrementing. That means that the `tempValue = i` but then the `i` is incremented. A `++i` should solve your problem.

Comment: As everyone else said you are saying tempVal=i++. That means that the value of tempVal will be changed on next execution. If you put it to be ++i then they will be the same at the beginning, like this it will be 5 and next time when executed it will be 0 as you wrote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're post-incrementing. That means that `tempValue = i` but then `i` gets incremented.

And why at the first iteration `tempValue` is still 5 ? There is a nice figure in OCA Programmer Guide

[image]

which explains every step during a for loop and what is essential here is that the *update statement* is executed **AFTER** *body* execution.

To be more specific, the figure is from *"Chapter 2 (Operators and statements)"* **(Figure 2.7)**

Answer (score 1):

The third clause of the for loop declaration is run AFTER the loop body. The i variable is incremented after the assignment to tempVal. 
So, unrolling your loop we would get the following:

```
// setup
int tempVal = 5;
int i=0;

// start of first loop iteration
System.out.println("Value Of i: "+i +" _tempVal:"+tempVal); 
// end of first loop iteration
tempVal = i; // 0
i = i+1; // 1

// start of second loop iteration
System.out.println("Value Of i: "+i +" _tempVal:"+tempVal); 
// end of second loop iteration
tempVal = i; // 1
i = i+1; // 2

etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

(1) You need to first understand the sequence in which `for` loop clauses execute. Debugger is a good tool to visualize the flow too.

The third clause (`tempVal = i++;`) in a `for` loop executes after the first iteration is over. Therefore, for the first iteration, where i is 0, the variable `tempVal` is still 5.

(2) You need to understand the difference between post (`i++`) and pre increment (`++i`).

What you are doing is a post increment. Therefore, the current value of `i` is assigned to `tempVal`. Then, i is incremented. If you were doing the pre-increment, `i` would have been incremented by 1 and then the final value would have been assigned to `tempVal`. Checkout the following snippet:

```
for(int i = 0, tempVal = i; i < 5; tempVal = ++i)
{
    System.out.println("Value Of i: "+i +" _tempVal:"+tempVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The update part of the for loop: `tempVal = i++` will happen *after* the first iteration. Then the value of 0 is assigned to `tempVal` because you use the post increment `i++`.

When you change `i++` to `++i` `tempVal` will be 1 the second time instead of 0.